# Convert Excel date from date serial number to Hijri date

Tags: date, excel, hijri, vba

I have a large report data, 30k+ rows in Excel, their are two values which have dates, the dates are in Hijri, 80% of the dates is correct, but a few values appear in date serial number, which is `40383` instead of `1432/8/12`, is there any way to convert those back to date, with this format, (`yyyy/mm/dd`) because I have written another function to calculate dates, and overlapping values, ...

Comment: I want the same result from this site: (http://www.calendarhome.com/calculate/convert-a-date/) when I put 40383 I got it as 1432/8/12 in Hijri and in Georgian I got it as 2010/07/11 but when I format the value as date in excel I got 2010/07/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-1170000]B2yyyy/mm/dd;@"
```